# Data and Database modelling books

Tags: self-learning, databases, data-types

I need a suggestion for books for my University. I have a subject called "Data and database modeling" but we lack of books. Our professor gave as barely understandable scripts. This is an official explanation of the subject:
**Curriculum:**

Introduction of data structures used in database modeling. 
The data structures include data objects, associations between objects and rules for performing operations over objects.
 
Modelling of databases regarding user demands. 

Basic database concepts. 

Configurations and commands for certain real databases. 

SQL commands for working with databases.

**Course goals/Competences:**

Data Modeling and design of data structures suitable for optimum operation of databases.

Using the basic set of SQL commands for working with databases.

Any suggestions are welcome :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend [Database: Principles, Programming, and Performance, by O'Neill](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558604383) and O'Neill. Learned from that book for my first database course and loved it.

Answer (score 1):

I worked as a data modeler at Siebel. One of the books that the Siebel data model is based upon is Data Model Patterns by David C. Hay. The book will not teach you how to build great data models. It is a collection of robust data models that are used in big systems used world wide.

The one book that I have used (in teaching) that focusses solely on data modelling is the text book "Data Modelling and Database Design" by Richard Scammel and Narayan S. Umanath.

Both of the above books are available on Amazon.com

Answer (score -1):

A simple search at Amazon for "database modeling" will turn up several books. Any of their top choices would be suitable.